# Attach entity in modified state without marking all properties dirty

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm trying to figure out how to mark specific properties of a detached entity as modified. If I do the following, it will mark all properties modified and the generated sql will update all columns.

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the entity in the modified state.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="entity">The entity.</param>
void IDbContext.Modified<T>(T entity)
{
    DbEntityEntry<T> entry = Entry(entity);
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
    {
        // if the state is already Modified we don't need to do anything else
        return;
    }

    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        Set<T>().Attach(entity);

        //TODO: set specific properties modified instead of the the whole object.
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

How do I set only changed properties as Modified?

I'm trying to use this in a class that implements `DbContext` that will be used by a generic repository. The goal is to automagically determine which properties have changed compared to the database values and then set those changed properties states to Modified. In my current implementation, the Modified method has no knowledge of the entity type, so I can't simply retrieve it with `context.Set<T>.Find(key)`.

I suppose I could add an overload that accepts an `originalEntity` parameter, but I'd rather not if possible.

```
void IDbContext.Modified<T>(T entity, T originalEntity)
{
    DbEntityEntry<T> entry = Entry(entity);
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
    {
        // if the state is already Modified we don't need to do anything else
        return;
    }

    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        Set<T>().Attach(entity);

        entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(originalEntity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must do it for each property manually by calling:

```
DbEntityEntry<T> entry = context.Entry(entity);
if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
    entry.Property(e => e.SomeProperty).IsModified = true;
    // TODO other properties
}
```

Edit:

Former example suppose that you don't want to reload the entity from the database and in such case you must know which properties are changed - it is up to you to implement it.

If you are happy with additional query to database you can use this:

```
var persistedEntity = context.Set<T>.Find(key);
var entry = context.Entry(persistedEntity);
entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
```

Edit2:

Setting original values should be reverse operation (but I have never tried this):

```
var persistedEntity = context.Set<T>.Find(key);
context.Entry(persistedEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;

var entry = context.Entry(entity);
context.Set<T>.Attach(entity);
// I'm not sure if you have to change the state of the entity
entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(persistedEntity);
```

Comment: How can I determine which properties are modified? Can I retrieve current values from the database and let the state manager figure it out?

Comment: @Ladislav: The question states that all of the properties are being marked as modified. You are showing how to mark individual properties as modified which is redundant here.

Comment: @Scott: I understand that OP doesn't want to mark all properties as modified.

Comment: @Ladislav: I think the key to your answer was not to set the state of the entity directly (as in the questiom) but rather through the properties that have changed.

Comment: @Scott: If so the answer is: Not possible when changes are done to detached entity because context doesn't know about them. It is possible only for attached / tracked entities and it is done automatically once you change a property.

Comment: I agree with you. I had missed the 'key' to your answer in my first comment.

Comment: The updated answer is close. I've updated my question with more detail on my scenario. I'm hoping some kind of entry.GetOriginalValuesFromDatabase() method that I haven't been able to find yet!

Comment: Yup, that works! Calling `entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(persistedEntity)` will update the state of each modified property.

Comment: In 1st approach if you set each property to `IsModified`, and down the line if you add new column to table then you have to go back and update the code